# What is the distribution of the cost function for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood

For linear regression, we try to find the parameter $\hat{\beta}$ that maximizes the likelyhood function
$$
P(\beta = \hat{\beta}|y) = L(\hat{\beta}|y) = 
N\exp{\big(-\frac{1}{2}(y - X\hat{\beta})^T(y - X\hat{\beta})}\big)
$$
where $N$ is a normalization coefficient. The argument of the exponential in this case is the cost-function. Writing this cost-function component wise, we have
$$
(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta) = \epsilon^T\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i^2 = \chi^2_{n-d}
$$
where $d$ is the degrees of freedom used in $X$. We know that if each component of $y$ is independently and identically sampled from some normal distribution, then $\chi^2_{n-d}$ follows a $\chi^2$-distribution.

For logistic regression, we have something a bit different. Instead, we have our data $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $y\in\{0, 1\}$, $E[y] = \bar{y}$, $E[(y-\bar{y})^2] = \sigma_{\bar{y}}^2$, and $E[y_jy_k] = \delta_{jk}$ where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker Delta Function.
A cost function for Logistic Regression used is
$$
\text{cost}(f_X(\beta), y) = -y\log(f_X(\beta)) - (1-y)\log(1-f_X(\beta)) \\
f_X(\beta) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-X\beta}}
$$
My question is, what distribution of $\text{cost}(f_X(\beta),y)$?

On that matter, we know from linear regression that $\beta \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{\beta}, \sigma^2).$ So I am wondering what $\beta \sim \text{?}$ for logistic regression?

Finally, given all of this, how would one derive all of these quantities from maximum likelyhood estimation?